# Search multi-dimensional array and create a new array from results

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to search a multi-dimensional array for a specific value and create a new array with the resultant data.

The original array is:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [make] => honda
    [type] => motorcycle
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [make] => toyota
    [type] => truck
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [make] => acura
    [type] => car
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [make] => subaru
    [type] => car
  )
)
```

The resultant array I would like:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [make] => acura
    [type] => car
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [make] => subaru
    [type] => car
  )
)
```

I anticipate using `array_search('car', array_column($arr, 'type'));` to get the key associated with the found values, but I am not certain how to utilize the found keys to obtain the new array?

Comment: I think `array_filter` would help here, I have provided an [example](https://3v4l.org/m9ciF)

Comment: I have updated my [example](https://3v4l.org/qog2Y) which now re-indexes the array

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, if all the `make` values are unique for `car`, and you only want the `make`, then you can index on that and use `array_keys` with the search argument:

```
$cars = array_keys(array_column($arr, 'type', 'make'), 'car');
```

Returns:

```
Array (
  [0] => acura
  [1] => subaru
)
```